# Ember - where to put the public site

Tags: heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm wrapping up my Ember application and I want to figure out the best practice for handling the public site (`/`, `/about`, `/faq`, etc). Ideally the Ember JS and the majority of the app itself wouldn't be loaded.

There are a couple options, but I'd like to know the best practice.

### Option 1 - Part of the app

Just make the public pages templates within ember-cli.

Pros:

- Same asset pipeline
- Single delivery of your entire site

Cons:

- How do you have two base templates? One for the public site and one for the app itself. Ideally I'd be able to have different nav bars for each part. Everything inherits from the `application.hbs` template but I don't want to put conditionals in there to handle the two nav bars. I also don't want to overwrite every other page in my app to put it under a different template (`/app/*`).
- The entire app would be loaded the first time the user goes to the page (only gets slower as the app gets bigger).

### Option 2 - Part of the public folder

Create static HTML in the `/public` folder.

Pros:

- Same asset pipeline
- Single delivery of your entire site
- Not loading the entire app for public pages

Cons:

- You have the write the entire HTML for every page. This doesn't allow for quick development.
- No template system. As the public site grows it's best to have a template so you can easily change the nav bar on all pages.
- Not sure how to handle `/` since ember-cli wants to handle that url, but I'd want it to be apart of the public site.
- Adds a lot of junk to your `public` folder since you'd need to add `about/index.html` for good urls.

### Option 3 - Separate from the ember-cli project/app

Create a nanoc site or some other statically generated site and deliver it for your public pages.

Pros:

- Have properly layouts for public site
- Separation of assets
- Not loading the entire app for public pages

Cons:

- Need to figure out how to properly deploy separate apps on the same domain (putting ember-cli under `/a/` is easy, but if I deploy to heroku how do I serve up multiple heroku apps on the same domain?).
- How should `/sign-up` and `/sign-in` be handled? Public site with public site chrome, or web app with a signed out state (not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Separate.

Use your .htacess file or whatever the equivalent configuration mechanism is for your server setup to control when your app should have responsibility for serving content and when it should not.